# How to find where postMessage came from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, shopify

I'm building a Shopify App using React/Redux. Everything is fine if I run it outside of the Shopify Admin dashboard but when I load it up as an embedded app in the Shopify Admin dashboard, it loads the app in an iframe and I get this postMessage error:

[image]

I have no idea where it's coming from but it only and have no idea how to find this. I do not perform any postMessage calls in my code at all so I'm assuming it's a dependency doing something or maybe `create-react-app` has something going on under the hood.

The console error does not give me a file either so I can't even debug it.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this message can mean two things:

1) You have not whitelisted the URL from the APP dashboard

2) Shopify can't connect to the URL address.

How to debug it?

Check your whitelisted URLs and see if there is `https://l46-vc-01.localtunnel.me` added there. And confirm that this is a static URL address and does not change each time you fire the tunnelling.

Check if you can access the URL address using a service that is not tied to your local machine. ( example https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ or https://geopeeker.com/ etc... )

Comment: They're all there. I'm thinking I'll have to do a masked redirect or a URL rewrite now

Comment: Found the issue, Shopify actually performs a postMessage to the iframe after it loads for some reason.